# HTML:Horizontal scrollbar is not appearing

Tags: html

I needed to include a scrollbar pane to a table,i`ve used a div tag for this,as below

```
<table border="2" width="100%"><th></th><th></th><th></th></table

<div><div width="100%" style="overflow:scroll;height:100px;scrollbar-face-color: #fff;   
scrollbar-track-color: #eee;position:fixed;height:300px;">

<table border="2" width="100%"><td></td><td></td><td></td></table></div>
```

Only verticle sroll bar is appearing,but not bottom or horizontall  sroll bar,Please suggest some answers.What wrong have i did?

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify width for the scroll, For scroll to appear you need to specify Height for vertical scroll, and width for horizontal scroll.

```
<div width="100%" style="overflow:scroll;scrollbar-face-color: #fff;scrollbar-track-color: #eee;position:fixed;height:300px;width:200px;">
```

As a sidenote, you have mentioned height twice in your inline style.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/deCMj/)